# How to pass expression as parameter into method

Tags: c#, expression

I have this piece of code for generic repository:

```
public PaginatedList<TEntity> Paginate<TKey>(int pageIndex, int pageSize, Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> keySelector) {

            return Paginate<TKey>(pageIndex, pageSize, keySelector, null);
}
```

How do I pass Expression parameter ?

Comment: Summary for Expression: This type supports the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Comment: @rmbq Um what? I think you are getting mixed up here.

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler converts lambdas to `Expression<Func<...>>` or `Func<...>` depending on the context, so you simply pass a lambda to `Paginate`:

```
var paginatedList = repository.Paginate(0, 10, e => e.EntityId);
```

Above, `e => e.EntityId` gets translated to `Expression<TEntity,TKey>`, where `TEntity` is the type of `TEntity` of your repository, and `TKey` is the type of `EntityId`.